# How to store Array in NSUserDefault in Swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsuserdefaults

So I've been trying for a few hours for a way to store an array to NSUserDefault and print them to the cells but the data is not saving as an array, it basically only saves one value at a time.

```
var emailData = [String]()
    var passwordData = [String]()

@IBAction func addPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

 let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    emailData.append(addEmail.text!)
    passwordData.append(addPassword.text!)

var storedEmail = defaults.objectForKey("emailData") as? [String] ?? [String]()
var storedPasswords = defaults.objectForKey("passwordData") as? [String] ?? [String]()


// then update whats in the `NSUserDefault`
    defaults.setObject(emailData, forKey: "emailData")
    defaults.setObject(passwordData, forKey: "passwordData")


// call this after you update
defaults.synchronize()        /*

 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setValue(addEmail.text, forKey: "email")
 NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
     */


}
```

So basically the data is not saving.

Comment: are you trying to print storedEmail & storedPasswords

Answer (score 4):

You can store Array too, by this way

```
let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let arr = ["abc","xyz","pqr"]
userDefault.setObject(arr, forKey: "arr")
userDefault.synchronize()

let data = userDefault.objectForKey("arr") as! [String]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Save the Swift Array in Swift.**

```
let kUserDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
kUserDefault.setObject(["KIRIT" , "MODI" , "FIRST" , "LAST"], forKey: "nameArray")
kUserDefault.synchronize()
```

**Get Array**

**1. arrayForKey :** You getting Swift Array

```
kUserDefault.arrayForKey("nameArray")!
```

**2. objectForKey :** You getting NSArray

```
kUserDefault.objectForKey("nameArray")!
```

**3. valueForKey :** You getting NSArray

```
kUserDefault.valueForKey("nameArray")
```

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to store arrays in NSUserDefaults. But separating email and password in separate array is not suitable. You should store it as one object since they are related.

In your case an array of Dictionary objects is better, which is possible to store in NSUserDefaults as well, which you can retrieve as an array of Dictionary.

Here is the sample:

```
    let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    var storedCredentials = userDefault.objectForKey("credentials") as? [[String:AnyObject]] ?? [[String:AnyObject]]()

    let email =
    [
        "email" : addEmail.text!,
        "password": addPassword.text!
    ]

    storedCredentials.append(email)

    userDefault.setObject(storedCredentials, forKey: "credentials")
    userDefault.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't save an array of [String] in NSUserDefault, if you look at the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:) :

> For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property
>   list objects.

So what you can do is convert your `[String]` into `NSData` then save it into NSUserDefault.

```
// Store it as NSData
var emailData = [String]()
emailData.append("email1")
emailData.append("email2")
let emailIntoNSData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(emailData)
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(emailIntoNSData, forKey: "emailData")

// Retrieve it : 
let emailFromNSData = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("emailData") as? NSData
if let emailFromNSData = emailFromNSData {
let emailArray = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(emailFromNSData) as? [String]
     if let emailArray = emailArray {
           NSLog("Email Data : \(emailArray)") // ["email1","email2"]
           // do something…
      }
 }
```