# Convert SwiftyJsonArray to NSArray

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, nsarray, swifty-json

I am using SwiftyJson for JSON parsing. I want to store the received array in LocalStorage using NSUserDefaults. But it is throwing error -

```
 "terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException"
```

My JSON response is like this :

```
    "store_list": [
        {
            "store_id": "3439",
            "store_name": "Anuraag",
            "city_name": "Dover"
        },
        {
            "store_id": "3440",
            "store_name": "Anuraag",
            "city_name": "Dover"
        },
        {
            "store_id": "3466",
            "store_name": "Anu 1",
            "city_name": "Miami"
        }]
```

So How to convert this array in NSArray so this can be saved using NSUserDefaults.
I have tried this but it is throwing error:

```
  self.store_list = data[0]["result"]["store_list"].arrayValue as! NSArray
```

where
store_list is an array of type NSArray.

Comment: If you are coding in Swift 4 Xcode 9 or later you should take a look at Codable protocol

Comment: This may help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36976066/how-to-store-array-in-nsuserdefault-in-swift

Comment: You don't need SwiftyJSON anymore now that there's the Codable protocol. You also should use Swift arrays instead of NSArray. And you shouldn't save such content in UserDefaults which is not made for this purpose...